# Get id of the record having Min() value

Tags: mysql

I have a complex mysql query where one of the Select fields is Min(value). Since all the 'values' are unique, is there also a way to get found min value's row id along?

In other words if we simplify the query to this question, it is like this:

```
SELECT t1.name, MIN(t2.value) AS minval
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id_user = t1.id
GROUP BY id_user
```

How can i now know which t2.id was chosen for lowest t2.value for particular user? Thank you!

Comment: What mysql version are you using?

Comment: latest mysql version

Comment: would be great if my overcomplicated real life example would simply have a mysql function which would also tell which row's id was chosen for the min value from table t2, that's the idea

Comment: both methods look complicated and add significantly more time to execute query in my case, will have to look for different solution then, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to find the first `value` of each `id_user`

You can replace `*` with the fields you need

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.id_user ORDER BY t2.value) as rnk
    FROM table1 t1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
        ON t2.id_user = t1.id
) as X
WHERE X.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this simple, dont know how complex your statement is:

```
   SELECT name,value,id
    FROM(
    SELECT t1.name,t2.value,t2.id
    FROM table1 t1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
        ON t2.id_user = t1.id
    GROUP BY t2.id,id_user
    ORDER BY t1.name,t2.id asc) as test
    GROUP BY name;
```